# rufus schedular to run a job at every day at some particular time from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rufus-scheduler

I am working with the `rufus` schedular to send sms every day, but I want to send the sms every day at 5 pm, I checked in the whenever gem and I can do something like:

```
every find_day.to_sym, :at => time do
    rake "followup_mail:send_mass_email[#{massemail.id}]"           
end
```

Time can  be like "4:20am".
Any suggestions on how to set this up with `rufus` scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
 recurrence_time = "17:00" #you can make it dynamic.
 scheduled_time = Midnight.parse("every day at #{recurrence_time}")
 scheduler.cron "#{scheduled_time}" do
  # do something every day, recurrence_time
 end
```

Here you can pass your recurrence from your database.
Hope it helps.

Comment: what is midnight?, how can i use that

Comment: Midnight is basically Alias for DateTime#beginning_of_day (0:00).

Comment: `initialize': not a valid cronline : '#{scheduled_time}' (ArgumentError) i am getting this error while runnig this code on the console.

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try following solution:

```
scheduler.cron '0 17 * * *' do
  # do something every day, 5pm
end
```

Comment: I dont think so, because we are fetching time from the database like:

"4:20am" and how should i convert it into the expression?

Comment: Why do you need to fetching time from database? Why not just set it as a constant because you already want to send sms at 5PM?

Comment: It's an example the time is being set from the ui.User will set the time when he want to send the sms to other user.